# How should I query posts in a recyclerview with only specific user id?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to use the Firebase UI recyclerview to display a series of posts by a specific user. I have a node called all_user_posts with the keys to each individual post. Is there a way to display the posts with only a specific user id in a key-value pair child? If anybody has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated

I am using Android Studio 3.2 with the newest dependencies for Firebase realtime database. For other recyclerviews in the same project I have displayed all posts by using:

```
DatabaseReference postReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("all_user_posts");
Query postQuery = postReference.orderByKey();
```

But is there a way do display only the posts that have a specific user id attached to the postKey?

```
private void displayAllPosts() {
    Query postQuery = postReference.orderByKey();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>().setQuery(postQuery, Posts.class).build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Posts model) {

            //post key in 'all_user_posts' node
            final String PostKey = getRef(position).getKey();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_post, viewGroup, false);
            return new PostViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `userId` in the database, then you can do the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseUser.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
Query postQuery = postReference.orderByKey().equalTo(user.getUid());
```

This will retrieve only data related to the `userId`